# What's best way/tool for sharepoint Analytics?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

We have online SharePoint site and we want to use tool or any way to get web site analytic ( the number of site visitors and page hits  .. etc ) ...  i do some searches but i couldn't till now to choose best tool that integrate with SharePoint to get this

Could any have any solutions for me ?

Comment: Belongs on serverfault or superuser. voted to move.

Comment: @Colin I think this question would be more relevant on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to see [SharePointSOS](http://www.sharepointsos.com/category/sharepoint-analytics/), also the Microsoft SharePoint blogs are a very good resource, then check [Silverlight Solution for SharePoint Usage Reporting and Analytics from Nintex](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/mikeg/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=1b3bbb8f%2D4b5a%2D4f72%2D94c4%2D94cb80bc3866&ID=967).